# excel vba: setting the formula to equal A or B if not found A

Tags: excel, vba

i have a vba line of code like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LOOKUP(""ETG_C"",RC[-10],RC[-8])"
```

i would like to know how is it possible to have the activecell formula be something else in the case that it does not find `ETG_C`

for example:

```
=if(not(LOOKUP(""ETG_C"",RC[-10],RC[-8]))) then =LOOKUP(""something_else"",RC[-10],RC[-8])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The key is to check first formula for errors with **ISERROR(value)** formula

this goes like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIRST_STATEMENT),SECOND_STATEMENT,FIRST_STATEMENT)
```

so in your case it should be like:

```
=if(iserror(LOOKUP(""ETG_C"",RC[-10],RC[-8])), LOOKUP(""something_else"",RC[-10],RC[-8]), LOOKUP(""ETG_C"",RC[-10],RC[-8]))
```